# datagrid value of the cell by column and row?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, cell

I'm using the WPF toolkit DataGrid.

How can I get the values of the cells by the row i and column j?

For example like this:
                       string s= datagrid1....[i][j];

i've viwed this but it doesn't work:

`for (int j = 0; j < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    string s=(dataGrid1.Items[i] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
                }
            }`

the error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Dour High Arch i've read it but i didn't found nothing specially...